# Existence of nontrivial bounded linear operator?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

Are there two normed spaces such that there is no nontrivial bounded linear operator between them:
$$\nexists T:X\to Y: T\text{ nontrivial, linear and bounded}$$

Comment: Take a one-dimensional subspace of $Y$ and use a non-trivial bounded linear functional on $X$ to construct a non-trivial bounded operator from $X$ to this subspace.

Comment: Only for $X = \{0\}$ or $Y = \{0\}$.

Comment: So there always exist nontrivial operators?

Comment: Can you explain the construction?

Comment: If you allow your norm to take value $\infty$, you could endow $Y$ with the (basically useless) norm $$ \| y\| = \begin{cases} 0 & y=0_Y \\ \infty & y \neq 0_Y. \end{cases}$$ In this case, the only *bounded* linear operator is trivial as long as there is some $0_X \neq x \in X$ such that $\|x\|< \infty$.

Comment: @Tom: Mhh that is not so satisfactory but thx anyway.

Comment: @DavidMitra: Ah did u mean: $Tx:=l_0(x)y_0$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Hahn-Banach Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hahn%E2%80%93Banach_theorem) gives us a wealth of nontrivial bounded linear functionals on (nontrivial) normed linear space $X$.  We can for example take the "coordinate" map on a one-dimensional subspace $\{ru | r \in \mathbb{R} \}$, $f(ru)=r$, and extend it to a map $F:X \to \mathbb{R}$ also of the same norm as $f$.

Then another nontrivial bounded map $G:\mathbb{R} \to Y$ can be defined by $G(r) = ry$ for any nonzero vector $y \in Y$.  The composition $T = G \circ F$ is then a nontrivial bounded linear transformation from $X$ to $Y$.

Comment: As answered in the Comments by David Mitra and Daniel Fischer.

Comment: This doesn't show that *any* normed spaces admit nontrivial bounded linear operators!

Comment: Why doesn't it?

Comment: Oh I'm sorry I overread the last sentence...